# Calculate percentage from access query record before display on listbox

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Have a access table with a empty record "congauge" that I want to show as a percentage when the listbox is displayed.  I have a record called "lastcon" which holds the string date of the last time I contacted a client. Need to show from 7 days what percentage is based on todays date and the "lastcon" date.

I tried adding this to the sqlquery string but not accepting it I get a error.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],congauge = (Datediff("d",Date,lastcon)/7)*100 as percentage,lastsn....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by removing the empty record place holder [congauge] turns out dont need this you can run a calculation in a query based on another record value and just insert where you want the calculation to appear on the fly in your query to feed to your excel listbox display. I'm using inverse % It counts down to 0.00% once it reaches the 7th day, then goes negative to show really past due.

second the format was not working because I was using double quotes.

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],Format((1 -(Datediff('d',cdate([lastcon]),Date())/7)),'0.00%'),

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes around the `d` in the `DateDiff` and do it like this if `lastcon` is a variable...

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],congauge = (Datediff('d',Date," & lastcon & ")/7)*100 as percentage,lastsn....
```

Comment: lastcon is a record not a variable

Comment: Then just change the double quotes to single quotes.It was difficult to know since you provided such a small amount of information.

Comment: I tried the following neither worked but at least not getting a  error.

Comment: Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],congauge = (Datediff('d',Date,' & lastcon & ')/7)*100 as percentage,

Comment: Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],congauge = (Datediff('d',Date,(SELECT [lastcon] FROM RecordList))/7)*100 as percentage),

Comment: got it to work without using the empty record congauge, but now only displays  decimals not the % symbol    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account Number],(Datediff('d',cdate([lastcon]),Date())/7),  I tried using format(value,"0.00") did not work

Comment: If you want the percent symbol, then you have to include it like this: `format(value,"0.00%")`